# Will Excel formulas be OK if they are imported within a spreadsheet into iPad Numbers?

Tags: ipad, ms-office, numbers

Will Excel formulas be OK if they are imported within a spreadsheet into iPad Numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general yes - but there are some functions that are only in Excel.

Googling found [this comparison](http://curmi.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/functions-in-excel-and-numbers-09.pdf) for Apple Numbers for Mac OS.